# ¿Por que el uso del try-except puede causar comportamientos extraños?

Tags: python, excepciones

Hay un usuario aquí que ha indicado más de una vez que el uso de try-except puede llevar a comportamientos inesperados. ¿Por que pueden ocurrir estos comportamientos y como puedo evitarlos?

Comment: No se quien votó el cierre, pero me puede decir que vio de opinión en la pregunta por favor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nota: esto está centrado en Python, pero podría aplicar a cualquier lenguaje de programación con manejo de excepciones.

---

Como dices, el try-except puede conllevar a comportamientos inesperados. Esto se debe a que un try-except puede capturar errores que no esperas que capture. A continuación, mostraré un ejemplo.

#### Ejemplo

```
class Persona:
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

persona = Persona()

try:
    persona.get_name()
except AttributeError:
    print("La persona no tiene el atributo 'get_name'")
```

El plan de este código es crear la clase persona, que podría o no tener el método get_name. Entonces usamos un try-except para capturar el AttributeError generado cuando intentamos acceder al atributo get_name y no existe.

Al ejecutar este código, nos sale el mensaje "La persona no tiene el atributo 'get_name'". Pero sabemos que no es verdad, ya que de hecho persona SI tiene el atributo get_name. Entonces, ¿por qué falló?

El error está dentro de la función, la cual intenta acceder al atributo name, el cual no existe, por lo que genera un AttributeError, el cual captura el try-except.

#### Anécdota

No tengo el código, pero una vez estaba ayudando a mi hermano a solucionar un extraño error con un módulo de terceros. El código de la función que hizo dejaba de ejecutarse desde cierta línea. Tardé en darme cuenta de qué estaba pasando. El problema era que el código del módulo que llamaba a su función era algo de este tipo (no recuerdo ni encuentro el código original, pero servirá para dar una idea):

```
funciones = {"funcion":funcion}

try:
    funciones["funcion"]()
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Estaba claro que el plan de este código era fallar silenciosamente si la clave "funcion" no se encontraba en el diccionario. Sin embargo la función se encontraba allí, se ejecutaba, y generaba un KeyError que era capturado por el try-except, fallando silenciosamente.

Este es otro buen ejemplo de un error que se capturó inesperadamente.

#### ¿Cómo evitamos esto?

En realidad no hay manera de evitarlo, solo reducir considerablemente la posibilidad de que ocurra. En lo personal, recomiendo los siguientes puntos:

##### El try-except como último recurso.

Trata de evitar en lo posible el uso del try-except a menos de que estés muuuy seguro de que no se capturarán errores inesperados o que no queda de otra.

**Bien**

```
if(hasattr(persona, "get_name")):
    persona.get_name()
else:
    print("La persona no tiene el atributo 'get_name'")
```

**Mal**

```
try:
    persona.get_name()
except AttributeError:
    print("La persona no tiene el atributo 'get_name'")
```

##### El menor código posible dentro del try

Poner código de más dentro de un try-except puede aumentar la posibilidad de que estos comportamientos extraños ocurran, ya que hay más código propenso a enviar errores, los cuales seguramente no quieras capturar.

**Bien**

```
try:
    a = int(input("Ingrese un numero"))
except ValueError:
    print("numero invalido")

print("El doble del número es", a * 2)
```

**Mal**

```
try:
    a = int(input("Ingrese un numero"))
    print("El doble del número es", a * 2)
except ValueError:
    print("numero invalido")
```

Si tu programa llama a una función que desconoces qué errores pueden generar, evita el uso del try-except, y más si el except es silencioso.

##### Solo captura ciertos tipos de excepciones

No captures todas las excepciones (`except:`), solo captura las que son del tipo que esperas. Entonces cuando ocurra un error inesperado, Python se encargará de mostrarlo como se debe.

**Bien**

```
try:
    a = int(input("Ingrese un numero"))
except ValueError:
    print("numero invalido")
```

**Mal**

```
try:
    a = int(input("Ingrese un numero"))
except:
    print("numero invalido")
```

##### Utiliza los datos del error

Esta última se me ocurrió mientras escribía esta respuesta. Algunos objetos que representan errores tienen atributos con datos sobre el error que podríamos usar a nuestro favor:

Por ejemplo, si solo esperamos capturar los errores de tipo 2 de [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) podemos usar lo siguiente:

**Bien**

```
try:
    open("archivo_inexistente")
    raise OSError()
except OSError as e:
    if(e.errno == 2):
        print("Error 2")
    else:
        raise e
```

Donde usamos el atributo errno para acceder al tipo de error y si no es el esperado, mostramos el error como tal con raise.

**Mal** (si es que esperamos solo errores de tipo 2)

```
try:
    open("archivo_inexistente")
    raise OSError()
except OSError as e:
    print("Error 2")
```

#### Un caso muy común de mal uso de try-except (opinión)

En varios módulos, [incluyendo los de la librería estándar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/65dd637840aa3d5f0686cc9add640f8a9e3acd1e/Lib/re.py#L129), se utiliza una forma de importar similar a esta:

```
try:
    import modulo
except ImportError:
    ...
```

El plan es que si no se puede importar modulo (lo que arrojaría un ImportError), se haga x acción (como establecer la variable modulo en None). Pero ¿qué pasaría si el módulo existe pero ocurre un ImportError dentro del mismo módulo? Ocurriría un comportamiento inesperado.

Una forma de evitar esto es usar [importlib.utils.find_spec](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec):

```
import importlib

if(importlib.util.find_spec("module") is not None):
    import module
else:
    ...
```

> Ojalá la comunidad de Python fuera más consciente del riesgo que implica el capturar ImportError de ese modo.