# bloquear ingreso de str en un input int python

Tags: python, input

Hola soy un nuevo estudiante de programación. Y mas allá de los cursos que hago quisiera ya formar parte de alguna comunidad para recibir ayuda.
Hoy estoy practicando algo básico, crear un script donde evalue un numero ingresado por una persona y de resultado de si es par o impar.

```
def ParImpar():
    numero = float(input('Introduce un numero '))
    print('Su numero es ', numero, ', ', end=(''))
    if numero % 2 == 0:
        print('por ende es Par.')
    else:
        print('por ende es Impar.')


ParImpar()
```

Esto claro funciona. Lo que quiero es realizar algo sin posibilidad de error. Es decir si alguien introduce caracteres no se quiebre el script, sino que de un mensaje de "eso no es un numero" o Directamente bloque el acceso de string, o de mas señales para hacer algo completamente funcional y que quede mas lindo el programa.

Gracias !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma común de pedir una valor numérico es usar un `try-except` para captura cualquier error en el ingreso y poner eso dentro de un `while` que sólo termina (con `break`) cuando las condiciones se satisfacen:

```
def ParImpar():
    while True:
        try:
            numero = int(input('Introduce un numero '))
            print('Su numero es ', numero, ', ', end=(''))
            if numero % 2 == 0:
                print('por ende es Par.')
            else:
                print('por ende es Impar.')
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Debe ingresar un valor enteror")
    return numero
```

Entonces, si se ingresa cualquier cosa no convertible a entero, se produce una excepción de clase `ValueError`, la que atrapamos explícitamente, generando un mensaje de error adecuado.

También faltaba agregar el `return`, para devolver el valor ingresado.

#### Demo

```
print (ParImpar())
```

produce

```
Introduce un numero abc
Debe ingresar un valor enteror
Introduce un numero 1.9
Debe ingresar un valor enteror
Introduce un numero 14
Su numero es  14 , por ende es Par.
14

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/546317/por-que-el-uso-del-try-except-puede-causar-comportamientos-extra%c3%b1os/546318#546318, en particular la sección "El menor código posible dentro del try". No creo que sea buena idea poner tanto código dentro de un try.

Comment: Genial ! gracias conozco los loops for y while. E igual intente if pensando que seria mas sencillo. Solo aun no conocía era la manera de captar un numero con try-except