# Cuando usar try-except y cuando if-raise en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excepciones

Estoy practicando con el manejo de excepciones en Python. He creado una clase Pila FIFO(First-In-First-Out). He encontrado dos formas de generar la excepcion que quiero y quiero saber si hay alguna más eficiente que la otra.

La clase es:

```
class FIFO:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__cola = []

    def put(self, elem):
        self.__cola.insert(0, elem)
        
    def get(self):
        valor = self.__cola[-1]
        del self.__cola[-1]
        return valor
```

Sin embargo, puede ocurrir que quiera llamar al método get() y que la pila esté vacia, lo que generaria IndexError.
Para manejar la excepcion he encontrado dos maneras. **Lo que quiero saber es: ¿hay alguna más eficiente que la otra o puedo usar la que yo quiera?**

```
    def get(self):
        try:
            valor = self.__cola[-1]
            del self.__cola[-1]
            return valor
        except IndexError:
            raise FIFOError
```

```
    def get(self):
        if (len(self.__cola) == 0):
            raise FIFOError
        valor = self.__cola[-1]
        del self.__cola[-1]
        return valor
```

**Nota:** FIFOError es una clase que he creado yo que es la que quiero que maneje la excepción en vez de IndexError

Comment: En términos de eficiencia no está claro cuál es mejor, y la última palabra la tendría el cronometrado de código (puede ser útil el módulo `timeit`). Pero aparte de cuestiones de rendimiento, hay cuestiones más "semánticas". Las excepciones deberían capturarse en casos excepcionales, es decir, casos que raramente ocurrirán y que cuando ocurren implican algún error de diseño o de uso en alguna otra parte del código. Tratar de sacar un elemento de una cola vacía no parece un caso así. Bajo este punto de vista a mi me parece más razonable el chequear la `len()` en lugar de "intentar y que rompa"

Comment: Por eficiencia, en tu caso, ambas opciones serían equivalentes. Por calidad del código me parece que el `if raise` es más indicado ya que sirve como un "guard" y explícitamente retorna la excepción deseada. El `try/except` es ideal cuando no se conoce de antemano la excepción que puede ocurrir o si se quiere agregar código para el manejo de esa excepción.

Comment: Al margen de lo que se pregunta (y lo que respondo en mi otro comentario), que sepas que las listas python tienen un método `.pop()` que hacen justo lo que intentas. Eliminan y retornan el último elemento, o generan un `IndexError` si la lista está vacía.

Comment: Entendido, y gracias por lo del pop() !

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses el try-except solo si es necesario y muy util. Lectura recomendada https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/546318/158880